# Javascript Alternative to appendChild

Tags: javascript, html, css, dom

I want to insert a node as a child node (element node ) at a fixed position(0) i.e. it should replace a child node (if there is one) and not append..

Which function should I use to ensure crossbrowser compatiblity?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Test to see if the element has a `firstChild`. If it has one, use `replaceChild` otherwise use `appendChild`

Comment: Thx a lot..Can we directly insert the child node without checking for existing...I mean I want it to be inserted/replaced at the same position...Also any example would be really helpful..

Comment: No. If you want to replace something `if` it is there, and append it otherwise, then you need to test for the condition.

Answer (score 0):

Select the child and use [`.replaceWith()`](http://api.jquery.com/replaceWith/)